# Php memory Limit Exceed, while runing Magento 2 Commands

Tags: magento, magento2

I tried to deploy static content of magento 2 but php memory limit exceed error pops up every time.
Even my cron jobs are not running it giving me the same error in cron.log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php -d memory_limit=2G in every command you run as a temporary solution to your problem but for permanent solution you must go for change in your php.ini file max_memory_limit to somewhat according to your requirement for Magento it must be minimum 765MB but you can give 2G for better functionality.

Comment: Welcome, No problem

Comment: Can we also use this in cron jobs?

Comment: Yes, We can also use this in cron jobs also